# Is it possible to use objects declared in useeffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use object declared in `useEffect` hook, like

```js
function App(){
  useEffect(() => {
    let myObject = .....
  }
  
  myObject.myFunction()
}
```

but IDE gives me an error that `myObject` is not defined...

I assume that it is not a good way to lead re-rendering objects declared in useEffect hook, but anyway, is there any way to use objects declared in useEffect hook?

Comment: Why are you creating the object inside useEffect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, because it's in different scope.

it would be ok to use state instead, because when useEffect call and object change, you wont get new value in object

like this :

```
function App(){
  const [myObject,setMyObject] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    setMyObject(...)
  },[])

  myObject?.myFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First your code is wrong. It's not `useeffect` it's [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), so:

```
useeffect(() => {
  let myObject = .....
}
```

should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let myObject = .....
}
```

Second you would use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) in this scenario:

```
const [ myObject, setMyObject ] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyObject(...)
  }, [])

  myObject?.myFunction()
```

Third make sure you're importing them correctly with something like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function So75221887() {
  const [ myObject, setMyObject ] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyObject(...)
  }, [])

  myObject?.myFunction()
}

export default So75221887
```